# Python - Data analysis of XML file with ElementTree

Tags: python, xml, python-2.7, xml-parsing, elementtree

this is going to be a pretty long question since my problem is quite specific and needs some explaning so sorry for that.

I Have a XML file that contains multiple 'spreekbeurten'. I want to obtain all the text from the spreekbeurten, the problem is that some spreekbeurten do not have a 'al-group' and some do. *(See code below for example piece ofthe xml file)*

```
  <handelingen>
      <spreekbeurt nieuw="ja">
        <spreker>   
          <voorvoegsels>De heer</voorvoegsels>
          <naam>
            <achternaam>Recourt</achternaam>
          </naam> (<politiek>PvdA</politiek>):</spreker>
        <tekst status="goed">
          <al-groep>
                <al>Much</al>
                <al>Very</al>
                <al>Hungry</al>
                <al>I am</al>
                <al>Hello.</al>
              </al-groep>
            </tekst>
          </spreekbeurt>

      <spreekbeurt nieuw="nee">
        <spreker>
          <voorvoegsels>De heer</voorvoegsels>
          <naam>
            <achternaam>Van Raak</achternaam>
          </naam> (<politiek>SP</politiek>):</spreker>
        <tekst status="goed">
          <al>Just one word</al>
        </tekst>
      </spreekbeurt>

  </handelingen>
```

I want to obtain the spreker his 'voorvoegsel' and 'achternaaam' with the corresponding text of the speaker. To do this I wrote the following code:

```
def extractingText(filepath):
    #Checking the size to keep empty files (size = 0 bytes) out!
    statsinfo = os.stat(filepath)    
    if int(statsinfo.st_size) == 0:
        return None

    tree = ET.parse(filepath)
    root = tree.getroot()
    #Hiermee kijken we naar handelingen (het gedeelte waar de gesproken stukken in staan)
    for handelingen in root.iter('handelingen'):
        spreekbeurt = []
        #Hiermee kijken we naar alle spreekbeuten van de personen
        for spreekbeurt in handelingen.iter('spreekbeurt'):
            achternaam = spreekbeurt.find('spreker/naam/achternaam').text
            voorvoegsel = spreekbeurt.find('spreker/voorvoegsels').text  
            #Defining what the text is, sometimes it is withn an al-group and sometimes it isn't
            text = spreekbeurt.find('tekst/al-groep/al') #<- TO FIX I SUPPOSE I NEED TO ADD A FOR LOOP HERE?
            if text == None:
                text = spreekbeurt.find('tekst/al')
            #Zoals je ziet heb ik nu voor alle spreekbeurten een text gevonden
            print text.text

    return None
```

The problem is that if the 'spreekbeurt' contains a 'al-group' I only get the first 'al' which is in the example 'Much' and not all the other words. How do I make sure that if the 'spreekbeurt' contains a  I pick all the text in the 'al' statements and not just only the first one?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

I believe your the answer is in [xml.etree.ElementTree.Element.findall](https://docs.python.org/2/library/xml.etree.elementtree.html#xml.etree.ElementTree.Element.findall) .
You then put the result in the list and check if the list as no elements.